# symfony5.4 - Unable to get data of OneToMany Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

Trying to store product browsing history for each user.

- I have a relation OneToMany between Product and History:

  ```
  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="History", mappedBy="user")  private $histories;
  ```

  ```
      public function __construct(){
          $this->histories = new ArrayCollection();
      }

      public function addHistory(History $history)
      {
          $this->histories[] = $history;

          return $this;
      }

      public function removeHistory(History $history)
      {
          return $this->histories->removeElement($history);
      }

      public function getHistories()
      {
          return $this->histories;
      }
  ```
- The reverse is set for the User class:

  ```
  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="histories") @ORM\JoinColumns({    @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
  ```

I want to get history from user.So I called `$user->getHistories()` , but resulting Collection is empty.

The following code should save the data correctly.

```
$history = (new History())
                ->setUser($user)
$entityManager->persist($history);
$entityManager->flush();
```

This can be said from the fact that the other field data is correctly stored in the database.

Oddly enough, after calling `$user->getHistories()->contains($XXX)` , the data I wanted to retrieve was stored in $user.
What on earth is going on?
Does anyone know why?
How can we get histories out of `$user` in the regular way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the result of $user->getHistories()->count() ? The lazyloading not loading data until you directly access to it

Comment: Oh, $user->getHistories()->count() give the number of histories.
And after this, $user->getHistories() can be used to get histories.
Thanks.

If lazyloading, do I always call a direct access method like count() if I want to get this kind of data?
 Or is there some other suitable method?

Comment: No, that mean you could access to $user->getHistories() on a foreach loop and read you data. The count was just to check if there is really no data or if just lazyloading. That just mean, seing no data when you dump a variable does not always mean data are no there

Comment: Oh, I see. So lazyloading reads the data when it references the data, so I can just use foreach as usual.
I did not understand its specifications.
Thanks, that helped.